# Obtaining part of string before question mark

Tags: r

I've got a table of strings like i.e.:

```
START0001?sthEND1,
START002?sthEND2,
START03?sthEND3,
START4
```

How could I obtain the table:

```
START1,
START2,
START3,
START4
?
```

I can do this with 
    gsub(sub('^([^?]+)*','',napis),"",napis)
but there is a problem with "?" sign that stays after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
y<-"START0001?sthEND1"
x<-unlist(strsplit(y,""))
idx<-which(grepl("\\?",x))
x<-paste0(x[1:(idx-1)],collapse = "")
x<-gsub("0","",x)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. What if START strings are not of the same lenght? I can do this with regular string, but there is a problem with "?" sign.

Comment: Look the answer again @JaroslawTwarog

Comment: @JaroslawTwarog, Does it work?

Comment: Works fine, thanks.

Comment: @JaroslawTwarog So give the answer as right please!

Comment: newstring <- gsub("\\?.*", "", oldstring)
I think this should work.

Comment: @Yes, understand, I refer put an upvote to my answer.